# field ,method,class based injection what is the difference? how we can use this injection?what changes we need for the serviceResource annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I need to know how field, class and method based injection work?
in my project I have used @service annotation.
to specify resource injection.
how this service annotation change depending on type of injection.

```
@ServiceResource(persistanceUnitName = "bookPU",
     dataSourceName = "java:/comp/env/jdbc/bookDS", 
    transaction = TransactionType.FRAMEWORK_MANAGED,
     database = Database.MYSQL)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSF